# UITableView Cell should not scroll horizontally swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a table view which has card kind of cells as shown in picture. 
I have set the content Inset so that I can get the cells with 20px spacing in left,right and top.
[image]
    tableVw.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 20)

Its displaying as I expected but the problem is, cells can be moved in all direction. But when I move it to right/top, it automatically comes back to original position. But when I move to left it just goes inside and don't scroll back to original position as shown in picture.
[image]

I don't want the cells to move at all or I want the cells to come back to centre if its dragged anywhere also. Please help!

Comment: You have add UIScrollview in cell ?

Comment: No. I don't have scroll view inside the cell

Comment: UITableview is default provide vertical scroll if you want to scroll horizontal then you should add UISCrollview.

Comment: I have asked for not to scroll. Now cells can be dragged in all direction. But I just want cells to stick in one place. User shouldn't able to drag the cells.

Comment: Please check my answer it may helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Dont provide uiedgeinsets to tableview instead add a view in uitableview cell that cover up the whole cell and add another uiview inside that view and give constraint from top bottom leading trailing equals to 8 or whatever you want then the cell wont move anyways and u tableview cells will look like it has edgeinsets.

Comment: Thanks. But i tried this earlier. I will be having a label inside cell which text will be dynamic.                                                                                                                       
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
    The height of a cell doesn't take properly

Comment: In tableview if you have dynamic cell sizes depending on the label text then you can achieve it with constraints and you dont have to implement the heightforrowatindexpath. just give label top leading trailing and bottom

Answer (score 0):

**If you're using AutoLayout, by setting this only should work for you:**

In code:

```
tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = false
```

or In Interface Builder:
Just find this option and untick "Bounce Vertically" option.

Here's the reference:

[image]

**If you're not using AutoLayout:**

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    // Enable scrolling based on content height
    tableView.isScrollEnabled = tableView.contentSize.height > tableView.frame.size.height
 }
```

**and also try clipToBounds**

```
tableview.clipsToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the `clipsToBounds` property `true`

`tableview.clipsToBounds = true`

Answer (score 0):

I achieved what I wanted by below code.

```
postsTable.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: -20)
```

And in UITableViewCell class :

```
override var frame: CGRect{
    get {
        return super.frame
    }
    set(newFrame){
        var frame = newFrame
        frame.size.width = kScreenWidth - 40
        super.frame = frame
    }
}
```

Now if I drag the cell left or right also its coming back to original position.